# Upload Image through ngx-CkEditor in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor

I am using ngx-ckeditor in my Angular7 project, I need to upload the file, it could be .pdf, .csv, .jgp etc. I have tried few options but i was not able to upload image through Editor. There is no such options over there, i am attaching the screen shot of the editor it has the option for attaching image through URL but i need to upload file from my local.

[image]

please help me in this,
thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?  How are you trying to upload the file?  Is it failing on the client or on the server?  What server are you using?  Try to include as much detail as possible so that the community can help you out better.

Comment: @VtoCorleone there is no such option to upload the file from the local machine, i just want to know how can i do this in ck-editor